# do you think http protocol mix character stream with byte stream is not a good design

Tags: java, http, protocols, implementation

Firstly,when I say **http protocol** mix character stream with byte stream,I mean **request head is character stream** and **request body is byte stream**(specified by content-length ),they are seperated by an empty line.

This design make http implementation more difficult.For example,if you use java to implement an http server,you can't use such code because BufferedReader will **buffer some bytes** for read a line.

```
InputStream   stream=socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
String line;
while( !(line=reader.readLine()).equals("") ){
    //do something with line
}
//from stream to read content-length bytes
stream.read(...)
```

It would be more easy to implement http protocol if it **use first two bytes to specified length of request head** instead of use empty line.

Comment: It's not the protocol that's broken. If you really do feel the need to implement your own HTTP library, take advantage of the fact that each character of the headers is ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just bad design ... it is broken.  The chances are that the `BufferedReader` will read the first part of the request body into its buffer.  So when you read from the stream at the end, you won't get all of the body.

Once you have wrapped an `InputStream` you shouldn't use it directly ... especially if the wrapper does buffering.

---

The best way to implement this is to use an existing HTTP Server-side implementation.  The Apache HTTP Components library is a good alternative to consider.

If you have to implement this yourself, then the simple solution is to:

1. Wrap the `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`.
2. Use the `BufferedInputStream` to read the header lines a byte at a time and build up the lines and convert to a String yourself.
3. Use the `BufferedInputStream` to read the body.

---

> I feel that the stupid design of HTTP protocol makes the `java.io` library useless.

I wouldn't say that.  The problem is that the HTTP protocol potentially requires a client to switch the way it interprets the characters / bytes of a request or response message halfway through the message.  But if you think about it, that is not an unreasonable thing to do.  The alternatives would be:

- to send separate messages which would increase the protocol overheads, or
- encode and send the request / response line and the headers as bytes rather than as characters.

What we really have is a tricky use-case that is too unusual to be supported in the generic `java.io` libraries.  A protocol support library would take care of this ... if you were able to use one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.My homework is to implement an simple http server without third-part library.I feel that the stupid design of http protocol make java.io library useless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it also would be easier to produce broken messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But do you mean current design is easier to produce **seperate(broken) message** or use first two bytes specified length of request head is easier to produce **bad(broken) message**.